# Shader is Black in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, baking

I know it's been said a thousand times. I've looked. But, nothing has worked.
I'm using a CellShading Shader I made, and I need to bake it.
I can't do this without switching to Cycles, though, and in Cycles, my Shader appears black.

I tried fixing it by following a post that said to convert the final color to a Diffuse BSDF, but that *also* didn't work.
What can I do to fix this? If any more information is needed, such as my full shader, etc., please ask me.

[image: CyclesImage]

[image]

Comment: If you don't mind the edit, I took the freedom to properly embed your file in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the object is coming out black is because you have 2 objects occupying the same place (one of them being black). Cycles does not like overlapping objects and will often yield black as a result (expecially if there is transparency involved). As you can see below (Image 1), in Material Preview mode (which uses an EEVEE based renderer), the black object appears as a nice black outline (as you intended), however in cycles (Image 2), the result is black, even with the "Correct" one (with the appropriate shader) selected.

[image: Mball1]

[image: Mball2]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I switched to rendered preview, and also changed the Material Output to All, but it's still Black in preview and when Baking

Comment: Did you check if you're using Cycles rendering engine in the first place?

Comment: @HikariTW, yes, I'm using Cycles

Comment: I also notice the color of your _material output_ node is wrong (grey, as if there were 2 and it was the "unselected" one - "selected" one should be red) - any chance you have a second material output node in your graph?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I only have one output node

Comment: Mball.001 and Mball.012 are in the same place - one is pure black - might this have something to do with the issue?

Comment: Shoot, that was it, sorry for the inconvenience. Mball.001 is the Outline object, which is *supposed* to be using Backface Culling, but when in cycles, it doesn't do that for some reason?

Comment: Yeah, cycles doesn't like overlapping objects (especially if there is transparency involved) and will most often give black as a result. If you want an outline, consider using _Freestyle_, or if need be, a _Line Art Modifier_.

Comment: I'm still having the baking issue, though. It's coming out as either pure gray (no lighting baked), or just black with some highlights (lighting baked), and the colors are smoothed, instead of the constant switch I wanted.

Comment: Were the objects overlapping when you baked the texture?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed it would bake right if the object was just hidden. I hid it from the render, and it baked properly. Thanks for mentioning that. If I haven't troubled you enough, how can I get the colors to act constant like how they do in Eevee?

Comment: It's more tricky - Shader to RBG used to be completely unavailable in Cycles shaders as it is not really compatible - toon shading is much harder to accomplish in Cycles than it is in eevee. That being said, it may still be possible (though I haven't done it in a whle) You need to make sure the texture is connected directly to the material output with no shader (BSDF) in between before baking. That way, it shouldn't try to add any interpolated shadows.

Comment: I've connected the Mix directly to the Output, but now it's just outputting a pure gray color that has no shading. Does Shade Smooth have something to do with this?

Comment: Yeah, nevermind. Like I said, I haven't baked textures in a while. Maybe it's best if I leave that advice to someone better equipped. If you want you can create a new question, only about the texture baking part, and/or how to bake toon shadows in Cycles.

Comment: Okay, thanks for all of the help so far.

Comment: @rezarg Just as a sidenote: When you asked for why the _Backface Culling_ doesn't do what it's supposed to in _Cycles_, Christopher said _Cycles_ doesn't like overlapping faces and would give most often black as result - well, that's not true in this case. The outline object is larger, so no overlapping, and if you would make the outline blue the object would show blue instead of black. The simple truth is, _Backface Culling_ only works in _Eevee_ which means _Cycles_ just renders the object normal as if no _Backface Culling_ was enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The preview panel you used is **EEVEE** instead of Cycles

[image]

Since you explicitly tell the shader that only output to Cycles engine, EEVEE doesn't get the result from shader.

You can either:

- Changing the output to all (yet if theres some invalid nodes for EEVEE, it might not work)
- Changing the Preview panel from Material preview to Rendered using <kbd>Z (hold)</kbd>, and making sure you are using Cycles as your rendering engine

Answer (score 0):

Here's an additional answer just in case you might want to create an outline object in *Cycles*. Of course you can use something like *Freestyle* or a *Line Art* modifier, this is just an alternative method. Although I think you're better off with *Eevee* since you use a lot of *Shader to RGB* nodes which simply cannot be used in *Cycles*.

As I said in the comments, *Cycles* does not use *Backface Culling*, it is only available in *Eevee*. Nevertheless there is the *Geometry* node in the *Shader Editor* which has an *Backfacing* output. This can be used to mix between a shader that creates the outline and a fully white *Transparent BSDF* to make the backfacing parts invisible.

I also woudn't recommend using a *Principled BSDF* for the outline because I guess you want a solid color outline and not reflections or anything on it. For a solid black outline the shader is very simple to create: Take a *Mix Shader* and plug a *Transparent BSDF* in the second *Shader* input, then plug the *Backfacing* output of a *Geometry* node in the *Fac*. The backfaces will be transparent and the front faces will be pure black without any shading (since there is nothing in the first *Shader* input):

[image: black outline]

This is when using your model, where you have already flipped the faces inside out to make the *Backface Culling* work. However, with the *Backfacing* output you wouldn't even have to flip the normals - you would simply plug the *Transparent BSDF* in the first *Shader* input.

Now this was the setup for a simple shadeless black outline. If you want to use a color (that's also shadeless), you have to plug in an *Emission* shader with a *Strength* of 1 into the other input. But that brings up a problem - the emissive color now illuminates the inner object from all sides becauses it encloses it completely:

[image: green outline illuminating scene]

So in order to make the outline only visible for the camera and not affect the rest of the scene, you can go to the *Object Properties* > *Visibility* > *Ray Visibility* and disable everything except *Camera*:

[image: ray visibility]

Now you just have the outline without any light shining on the other objects.

[image: green outline]

What is a little bit inconvenient though is that would have to change the *Visibility* settings on each object that you want to work as an outline. With a slightly more complex shader setup this won't be necessary though: if you take another *Mix Shader* node and a *Light Path* node, you can use the *Is Camera Ray* as mix factor between the *Transparent BSDF* plugged in the first *Shader* input_ and the result of the first *Mix Shader* into the second input. This makes the camera see the outline correctly while for the rest of the scene objects the outline is completely invisible and thus does not illuminate anything. This way you can simply put this material on any object that should work as an outline without the need to change the *Ray Visibility* settings (although for *Eevee* you still would have to change settings per object).

[image: setup with light paths]

In the above screenshot the first *Mix Shader* is set up for non-flipped normals, just in case you're wondering. By the way, with this setup you can use the outline in both *Cycles* and *Eevee*. To make it work in both you can use the following variations:

- The normals of the outline objects are flipped - in this case, the *Transparent BSDF* goes into the second input and for *Eevee* you can either enable *Backface Culling* or set *Blend Mode* to something else then *Opaque* like *Alpha Hashed* for example.
- The normals are oriented correctly - then you plug the *Transparent BSDF* in the first input and you cannot use *Backface Culling* in *Eevee* but have to set *Blend Mode* to something like *Alpha Hashed*.

Now the only problem you might have is when you have *Bloom* activated in *Eevee* or want to add some glow in the *Compositor*, the *Emission* shader will be glowing. You might have to adjust the *Threshold* to some value that the outline does not start to glow and other objects that should glow are brighter, or work with masking in the *Compositor* (but that's stuff for a different question on how to separate those things in compositing).